# How to create an Azure AKS service through ARM Template

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-rm-template

I am working on Azure Kubernetes service. I am creating AKS through portal successfully. But, I need to do it through the ARM Templates.

How to create AKS with help of ARM Templates?

For this, I followed [link](https://github.com/neumanndaniel/armtemplates/blob/master/container/aks.json)

But, here am receiving an issue like:

> Code    : InvalidTemplate
>
> Message : Deployment template validation failed: 'The template
>   resource 
>             'AKSsubnet/Microsoft.Authorization/36985XXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-5fb6b7ebXXXX'
>   for type 
>             'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/providers/roleAssignments'
>   at line '53' and column '9' has incorrect segment lengths. A 
>             nested resource type must have identical number of segments as its resource name. A root resource type must have segment length 
>             one greater than its resource name. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template/#resources for usage details.'.

Comment: Does the template you posted not help you with the AKS?

Comment: Yes, It is not helped for me because there is a sshkey relatre to Linux VM as a parameter in that template example. But, my OS is WIndows10 and it is not possible to cretae Linux sshkey

Answer (score 1):

> How to create AKS with help of ARM Templates?

One of the most direct methods, navigate to creating AKS page in the portal, fill the attributes, click `Download a template for automation`, then you will get the template.

[image]

You could test the template in the **Custom deployment**, it will work fine.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Joy Wang. I tried like this method also, here am getting the type and name mistake error at Rolebased assignment resource creation

Comment: @Mani Could you update the specific template and error message in your question?

Comment: @Mani The error caused by my template? Or the template in your link? In my template, it seems not mentioned vnet and works fine on my side.

Comment: Yes, you are right "When we go with basic networking in Network-Template and its work fine to me also", but "when we go with Advance networking in Network-Template" then am receiving this error

Comment: @Mani I test it with Advanced Networking, it works fine on my side. Refer to https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aMhP.png

Answer (score 1):

Old thread but here is why the AKS Advanced Networking ARM Template is not working for you.

One of the steps in the deployment assigns the SP as a contributor to the newly created AKS subnets so that the SP can work its advanced networking magic.

In order to assign a role in a RG one needs to have Owner permissions on that RG.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have provided the incorrectly formatted string in the "name" field of the resource. It should follow the pattern like this- "{resource-name}/Microsoft.Authorization/{role-assign-GUID}"

More on this here- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-template#resource